Google Query - Sort last column ASC where I don't know the number of columns
I have a query in google sheets:
=query('GA4 - Product Data'!A:N,"SELECT D, SUM(H) GROUP BY D PIVOT N",1)
What I would like to do is sort this data by the final column from the pivot, which I usually do by wrapping in another query:
=query(query('GA4 - Product Data'!A:N,"SELECT D, SUM(H) GROUP BY D PIVOT N",1),"SELECT * ORDER BY Col13 DESC",1)
The problem is that the data I'm querying extends each day, and soon it will have an extra months worth of data, so the pivot will be 14 columns long rather than 13 and my sort won't work.
Is there a way in query so "always sort the final column" somehow? so its more dynamic than what I have?
thanks for any help.
tried googling but not sure where to go next

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

There is more than one way, but similar to what you have, you can use LET to name the first QUERY, and then use it to apply it and find the amount of columns:
=LET(q,query('GA4 - Product Data'!A:N,"SELECT D, SUM(H) GROUP BY D PIVOT N",1),
query(q,"SELECT * ORDER BY Col"&COLUMNS(q)&" DESC",1))


Amazing thanks for the quick reply and solution. It's worked great on the data. I understand the &columns now, just need to get my head around =let. thanks so much though

LET allows you to create variables, naming steps of the calculations, like in this case. If you wouldn't use LET, you should have to rewrite inside COLUMNS, but instead of that you just name "q" - or however you want - that first result and reuse it any times you want
